# How to map sub domain to internal IP adress

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-http-server, dnsmasq

I'd like to reach some internal services like the web client of my NAS (Synology DSM) through dedicated sub domains like `https://nas.example.com`.

The services are fully running and accessible via internal IPs like `https://192.168.0.200:5001`.

I obviously own the domain `example.com` and have an Apache server up & running.

There are basically 2 reason why I'd like to achieve the above:

- The sub domain `nas.example.com` is easier to remember than `192.168.0.200:5001`
- I'd like to use my existing HTTPS certificates for `nas.example.com` which I can't with internal IP addresses

I've already played around with Apache's `mod_rewrite` but had no success at all. Unfortunately I can't tell if this scenario is even possible with `mod_rewrite` or if I just didn't configure it correct.

Some notes:

- The services should not be accessible from outside but only from within my LAN.
- Ideally, they should also be accessible via the sub domains when connected with the network from outside via SSH tunnels. Therefore a dedicated DNS server like `dnsmasq` is not what I'm looking for since that would only treat requests from within the LAN (I guess...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to do with nginx, but apache can handle this too, using [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html)

You should set up a VirtualServer for domain nas.mysite.com and enable Reverse Proxy for this virtual server:

```
ProxyPass "/"  "http://192.168.0.200:5001"
ProxyPassReverse "/"  "http://192.168.0.200:5001"
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother setting up a reverse proxy when:

> The services should not be accessible from outside but only from within my LAN.

Simply create a DNS record that points `nas.example.com` to your IP-address

```
nas.example.com. IN A 192.168.0.200
```

Non-internet routable ip-addresses from the 192.168.0.0/16 subnet will only work within your own LAN.

Then configure the DSM web interface to run on port 80, the default port for HTTP and you won't need to use a port number like 5000 in the URL anymore.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that point

Comment: FYI: If I could I would have also accepted your answer since it showed an easy alternative I wouldn't have thought of before but I chose the one with reverse proxy since it opens up more options for me. Thanks either way!